# Append user textField input into array in other view controller

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

So I've been searching for a solution that I can understand and apply to my project, but no luck.

I have a popup window(viewcontroller1) with a `UItextfield`. In this field, the user should enter a text that appends into an array in another view controller(viewcontroller2)
 I've tried something with `prepare(for segue)` but that will also transfer the user back to viewcontroller1, right?

So how would I append and save this UItextField data to the array in viewcontroller2, without automatically moving the user when he/she hits enter?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `delegates` or `notifications` to achieve this.

You need to call the delegate function as the user finishes editing(may be a "save" Button will give you the callback that that the user has finished entering). For more information on delegate refer [this](https://medium.com/compileswift/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef).

Answer (score 1):

Make your array variable as 'static'.

```
static var arrayElements = [String]()
```

You can modify this array from anywhere in your project by using

```
viewcontroller2.arrayElements
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `NotificationCenter`. In your ViewController2 add observer (Swift 3 Version):

```
func viewDidLoad () {

  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(arrayUpdateNotificationReceived :), name: "TextFieldInputChangedNotification", object: nil)
}

func arrayUpdateNotificationReceived (notification : Notification) {
      yourArray.append(notification.object);
}
```

In ViewControlller1 :

When user clicks add on popup :

```
@IBAction func yourButtonAction(sender : UIButton )  {

   let inputText = inputTextField.text;

   notificationCenter.post(name: "TextFieldInputChangedNotification", object: inputText)
}
```

Don't forget to remove observer in your ViewController 2 :

```
deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure that is correct but I'm trying to do this in swift and if I'm not mistaken that's objective C? Thank you anyway!

Comment: Here's a swift 3 version :)

Comment: Thank you for translating this to swift, seems like im using swift 4 and the somewhere in the NotificationCenter the code is depricated and doesnt work. But anyways thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to use the data entered into the `UITextField` immediately in `ViewController1`, you can use `prepare(for segue)`. This function doesn't actually start the `segue`, but it is called by the system automatically when a segue is about to happen either by selecting a UI element that has been connected to a `segue` in `InterfaceBuilder` of by reaching a piece of code, which calls `self.perform(segue)`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you enter the text from the textfield, do you want the user to be taken to `ViewController2` or remain in `ViewController1`?

If you are looking to take the user to the 2nd view controller after entering this data then you can pass this string in a segue to the 2nd view controller.
To do this, in the `ViewController2.h` file, add a new property to the 2nd view controller as a string.
When you do your performSegueWithIdentifier pass it the string you entered as a sender, and in the prepare for segue, set `viewController2` as your `segue`.`destinationViewController`, and then you can set `viewController2.string` to the sender.

If you are just looking to have it appended, I suggest creating a new class of a shared instance or singleton object. This instance or object would have an array that would maintain it's values irrespective of which view controller you've entered. 
You can have a look at this question's preferred answer, might help: [Objective-C Defining a Global Array for use by several ViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638881/objective-c-defining-a-global-array-for-use-by-several-viewcontrollers)